# Inappropriate upvoting (example provided)

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that someone is going through and (it appears) disingenuously upvoting my posts. I'm not sure how to figure out who it is. While I appreciate the gesture, it's much more valuable for content to be accumulate vote organically as users find certain posts helpful (or not).

Note the timestamps. Is there anything to do about this?
[image]

Comment: I also had this couple of times. I contacted SE stuff and they told not to pay much attention. So what actually is your question? :-)

Comment: Heh, I asked the question in my head, @Tim! "Is there anything to do about this?"

Comment: serial upvotes are reverted automatically. if not, enjoy the fame :-)

Comment: I had this, too. The majority were reversed at the end fo the day.